# Moving from python to node

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, express, axios

I have been using this python code snippet for years:

```
payload = {'grant_type': "password",
           'username': "me@me.com",
           'password': "mypassword",
           'client_id': "7xxxxxxxx",
           'client_secret': "jxxxxxxxx",
           'scope': 'read_presence read_thermostat'}

try:
    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.acme.com/oauth2/token", data=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json())
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
    print(error.response.status_code, error.response.text)
```

Now I am in the need to move the same code to node/expressjs. I have tried with this code, but it always responds with "400: Bad request":

```
app.get("/get_codes", (req, res) => {
  const axios = require('axios');

  const options = {
    grant: 'password',
    username: "me@me.com",
    password: "mypassword",
    client_id: '7xxxxxxxxxx',
    client_secret: 'jxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    scope: 'read_presence read_thermosta'
  };
  const params = Object.entries(options)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('&')

    axios.post('https://api.acme.com/oauth2/token', params)
    .then(response => {
      res.send(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried [debugging](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) ([sample configuration for VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)) to see, where your code gets stuck? Can you observe anything else like an exceptionally long loading time?

Comment: In addition, to me it looks like you want to send a token request according to the OAuth protocol. Which content-type/request Format does your actual service expect?

Comment: It is not hanging, and there are no errors in the code. It simply respond with "Bad Request". The python code is working without setting any header, in any case it is form-encoded. It is an expressjs application.

Comment: So the "Bad request" is what you are receiving inside the `catch`?

Comment: So the Python version uses `grant_type` while the Node JS version uses `grant`?

Comment: AARGH! One week on pain for just a typo!! Man, you got it. It was `grant_type`, but now I have another problem. The response is empty. I believe that the 2 responses (one from app.get and the other from axios.post) are interfering...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to send your data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you should prefer using the [URLSearchParams API](https://github.com/axios/axios#urlsearchparams) for serialization:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(options)
```

If you have to serialize it yourself for whatever reason, you can pass the content type header explicitly:

```
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
  data: params,
  url: 'https://api.acme.com/oauth2/token',
};
```

---

And of course have a look at your spelling, as @qrsngky pointed out in the comments ;)